# how to fix a height & width of div by css

Tags: html, iframe

I want to know if i have a iframe window and i am opening it in a Div. but i want to show only a fixed area of that iframe in the div how it is possible with css.

See,

I have a iframe window

```
<iframe src="http//www.examplesite.com/" height="200" width ="800"></iframe>
```

i need to open it inside a div. but my problem is i can not change in the iframe code. please do not advise me for that.
i want to show only 700 width and height 175 inside a div.
you can say that i just want to show 3/4 part of the iframe in a div.

Is that possible. 
if the answer is yes then how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be u can try this

```
<div style="height:175px;width:700px;overflow:hidden"><iframe src="http//www.yahoo.com/" height="200" width ="800"></iframe></div>
```